# Reference Request: Oracle applications outside cryptography

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, computability, oracles

Oracles have been used to prove results in cryptography where all parties have access to a random oracle instantiated with some cryptographic primitive. I am looking for references to papers that have specifically considered applying oracles to decision problems in some specific domain/field. I am just looking for general pointers and do not have a specific domain in mind.

Comment: hardware verification effectively uses SAT as an oracle, since there are efficient SAT solvers. I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for though

Comment: Thanks Suresh, i did not know about h/w verification: but thats not the kind i was looking for

Comment: If you consider a common coin randomized consensus algorithm, all parties have access to an oracle, which at each round of the protocol reads either 0 or 1, with some probability, to all the parties who read it during that round. The next round the value is changed randomly again. One ref. might be "Simple and efficient oracle-based consensus protocols for asynchronous Byzantine systems (2005, R Friedman, A Mostefaoui, M Raynal)"

Comment: Many worst case analysis is done as a game played against an all powerful adversary; that is, an oracle. I think this is even more explicit in the analysis of some online algorithms.

Comment: @M.Allagan: Thanks, that is something along the lines i was looking for, i will read the paper in more detail to understand

Comment: I assume you know about natural proofs, relativizing vs non-relativizing proofs, and the like?  That line of work shows that certain kinds of proofs will never be able to prove that $P \ne NP$ (for instance), and those kinds of proofs can be characterized because they relativize: they remain valid with respect to an arbitrary oracle.